# Generic Comparator

Tags: java, comparator

This is for a school project.  I have a `Query<E>` class that holds an element that is part of the `Query` condition.  So if it's a `GreaterQuery` and the element is 10, all values greater than 10 pass the condition.

The constructor of this `Query` object takes the element, and a `Comparator` object to be used to test the condition.  If null is passed in, I need to create a `Comparator` to use for the comparison.

I have a `match(E element)` method that tests the condition.  Here's bare bones version of it:

```
public boolean matches(E element)
{
    if (comparator == null)
    {

    }
}
```

What I thought I could do was write an anonymous `Comparator` class inside the `if` statement, though I'm not sure if that's even possible.  The other problem I'm having is how to even compare to `E` objects without knowing anything about them.  Also, I'm not sure of this, but there may be a pre condition that `E extends Comparable`.  It's very late and I apologize if this makes no sense.  But any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `E` is guaranteed to implement `Comparable<E>`, you can do this:

```
if (comparator == null) {
    comparator = new Comparator<E>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(E lhs, E rhs) {
            return lhs.compareTo(rhs);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: `GreaterQuery` would need to be have declaration something like `public class GreaterQuery<E extends Comparable<E>> { ... }` to make this work (which I think answers the OPs question on preconditions).

Comment: Would that help compare E?  Wouldn't that just give GreaterQuery the ability to be compared with compareTo()?

Comment: @webhound: That does compare two instances of `E`. Notice it says `class GreaterQuery<E extends Comparable<E>>` (which means `E` must be comparable), not `class GreaterQuery implements Comparable<GreaterQuery>` (which means `GreaterQuery` itself is comparable).

Comment: Ohh, yeh, I mis-read that.  That does make sense.  Now I'll have to make sure it's ok for the project.

Comment: @webhound: If `Comparable` isn't guaranteed, then the comparator must be specified. How else are the comparison rules going to be specified? :-)

Comment: @Chris: that's what I've been trying to figure out.  There's no basis for comparison since the object is a mystery.  I'll have to talk to my professor.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sort of funny, the whole lab got dropped and replaced.  Not just because of the Comparator, which was straightened out, but because the Visitor pattern was broken.

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 8 there is a [method in the standard library](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--) which does the exact thing that is showed in Chris' answer:

```
if (comparator == null) {
    comparator = Comparator.naturalOrder();
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's the standard way to do it these days. But even if that method didn't exist, it's easy enough to just use `comparator = E::compareTo;`.